# Playing sound from web page for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm developing a site for mobile devices (such as iPhones and Androids). And I would like to have a scenario when user clicks a button and hears a sound from audio-file (.wav for example). Is it possible to achive it somehow?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just add in a link or embed the file into the html for your site.  Here is some info on it:

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/iphoneaudio.html